# how to upload archive.zip with manifest.json in jfrog artifactory

Tags: json, artifactory

Try to upload 3 files in to archive.zip with manifest.json like the following, but don't know how to do it. It seems artifactory only let me upload the files, but does not generate the manifest.json.

```
{
   "path": "xxx/xxx/xxx/windows",
   "name": "AHK",
   "version": "1.1.34.04",
   "archived": true,
   "archive": {
      "name": "archive.zip",
      "size": 444712,
      "date_modified": "2022-08-23T21:23:09.4878027-07:00",
      "checksum": "e2c3d3c8ce1b6b9945f33ea5a41e12313b8b0be4",
      "full_checksum": "879639b974421e1100208c65869916faa3cb535e"
   },
   "created": "2022-08-23T21:23:09.3817945-07:00",
   "checksum_bytes": 16384,
   "files": [
      {
         "name": "AutoHotKey_version.txt",
         "uri": "AutoHotKey_version.txt",
         "folder": false,
         "size": 320,
         "date_modified": "2022-08-23T17:59:43.2923252-07:00",
         "checksum": "540adbb4537ad52b75213ef148114364cdd4b801",
         "full_checksum": "540adbb4537ad52b75213ef148114364cdd4b801"
      },
      {
         "name": "AutoHotkey.exe",
         "uri": "AutoHotkey.exe",
         "folder": false,
         "size": 791040,
         "date_modified": "2022-08-23T00:49:49.9812873-07:00",
         "checksum": "dd3095a8d157e1dfdc6428929f57c7792b2ac411",
         "full_checksum": "02c3e7d959778facef26a3252ab895c93e9657fe"
      },
      {
         "name": "license.txt",
         "uri": "license.txt",
         "folder": false,
         "size": 18120,
         "date_modified": "2020-10-23T00:49:01-07:00",
         "checksum": "3d436ffdd69f7187b85e0cf8f075bd6154123623",
         "full_checksum": "3d436ffdd69f7187b85e0cf8f075bd6154123623"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What is your package manager? What is the repository type in Artifactory?

Comment: Jfrog Artifactory, don't know what is package manager. Tried to use jf.exe to upload.